# If File type does not exist, color label green

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I'm trying to find a script that when run through [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) (on OS X) looks for the file type `.partial` within a folder, and if it is not found, label the contents of that folder green, so that Hazel can then do other things with it.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in  `Applescript Editor`:

```
set myFolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
set folderContents to the entire contents of myFolder
end tell
set folderItems to the number of items in folderContents
set x to 1
repeat
    set myFile to (item x of folderContents)
    set theFileName to myFile as text
    if (text ((offset of "." in theFileName) + 1) thru -1 of theFileName) is equal to "partial" then
        return
    end if
    if x is equal to folderItems then exit repeat
    set x to (x + 1)
end repeat
tell application "Finder"
    set y to 1
    repeat
        set greenRepeat to item y of folderContents
        set label index of greenRepeat to 6 --green
        if y is equal to folderItems then exit repeat
        set y to (y + 1)
    end repeat
end tell
```

This script will tell you to select a folder. It will then cycle through all the files in that folder and if it doesn't find a file of the type `.partial`, it will colour all the files in that folder green.